# Menu Slider programaticamente

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Estou criando um menu programaticamente, eu instancio o menu no meu home e quando clico no botão que vai puxa o menu, o menu aparece porem não consigo interação, não consigo clicar nas células, quem esta com a prioridade é a home e não o menu, como faço para que quando eu clicar no botão e puxar o menu ele fique com a prioridade?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    menuViewone =[[UIView alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 568)];
    [menuViewone setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:menuViewone];

    menuViewController = [[ITMenuViewController alloc] init];
    menuViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 568);
    [self.view addSubview:menuViewController.view];

    btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(pushMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setTitle:@"push" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(40, 300, 240, 40);
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
    btn.tag = 1;
    btn.clipsToBounds = YES;
    //set other button properties here.
    [self.view addSubview:btn];

}

- (void)pushMenu {
    if (menuViewController.view.frame.origin.x < 0 && btn.tag == 2) {
        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
            menuViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 568);


        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            btn.tag = 1;

        }];
    }

    if (menuViewController.view.frame.origin.x >= 0 && btn.tag == 1)
    {
        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{


            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 0, 320, 568);
            menuViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width + 0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 568);
            [self.view.layer setCornerRadius:4];
            [self.view.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
            [self.view.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
            [self.view.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.5f)];


        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            btn.tag = 2;

        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Está usando alguma biblioteca? Como está abrindo o menu? Algum código pra nos mostrar? Acrescente algumas informações nesse sentido que vai facilitar a ajuda.

Comment: Adicionei o código